# How to get xcode just for dependencies without installing 10gb of gui?

Tags: node.js, xcode, macos, npm

xcode is over 10gb but I only need it to get some dependencies in the cmd line tools and install packages for nodejs. Without it I cant even set the compiler for bootstrap 4.

Is there a lightweight option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Terminal to try and install only command line tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Alternatively, you may also try go to the [Apple developer website](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) (Downloads > more downloads section), and, once you are logged in and have accepted the agreement, you may download the package for the command line tools from there.